# Bash script not piping through commands

Tags: bash, macos, awk, grep

I have the following bash script running on Mac El Capitan that does not produce the correct output, but when I  ran a sequence of these same commands on the command line, it worked. I am trying to create a bash script so I don't have to do these commands every time I want to find the parent directories of the files in the logs that generate a certain error code.

Here is a redacted excerpt of a log file:

```
[2016/06/16 18:11:38] [12.34.56.789] [username] [R] D/Data/Shared/Files/ABC Real Estate - Not the bridge Project/Formal Discovery/001 Drafts/
[2016/06/16 18:11:39] [12.34.56.789] [username] [R] D/Data/Shared/Files/ABC Real Estate - Not the bridge Project/Formal Discovery/2016-04-27 Docs from OC (to be processed)/
--
--
[2016/06/17 15:57:20] [12.34.56.789] [username] [R] [Upload] [D/Data/Shared/Files/ABC Real Estate - Not the bridge Project/Formal Discovery/2016-04-27 Docs from OC (to be processed)/12-15-13 IW CCTV Inspect/My Pane/3637/2013.08.14_0922/SnapShots/36_37_MGP_101.4.jpg] [182.27 KB]
[2016/06/17 15:57:26] [12.34.56.789] [username] [R] [Upload] [D/Data/Shared/Files/ABC Real Estate - Not the bridge Project/Formal Discovery/2016-04-27 Docs from OC (to be processed)/12-15-13 IW CCTV Inspect/My Pane/3637/2013.08.14_0922/SnapShots/36_37_MGP_330.2.jpg] [174.96 KB]
[2016/06/17 15:57:26] [12.34.56.789] [username] [R] Number of files considered for upload: 999
[2016/06/17 15:57:26] [12.34.56.789] [username] [R] Number of files uploaded: 135
[2016/06/17 15:57:27] [12.34.56.789] [username] [R] Number of files in sync: 864
[2016/06/17 15:57:27] [12.34.56.789] [username] [R] idevs error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at main.c(1234) [generator=1.0.19]

[2016/06/17 09:37:08] [12.34.56.789] [username] [R] receiving file list
[2016/06/17 09:37:17] [12.34.56.789] [username] [R] D/Data/Shared/Files/ABC Real Estate - Not the bridge Project/Formal Discovery/2016-04-27 Docs from OC (to be processed)/12-15-13 IW CCTV Inspect/My Pane/3738/
[2016/06/17 09:37:17] [12.34.56.789] [username] [R] D/Data/Shared/Files/ABC Real Estate - Not the bridge Project/Formal Discovery/2016-04-27 Docs from OC (to be processed)/12-15-13 IW CCTV Inspect/My Pane/3738/2013.08.14_0941/
[2016/06/17 09:37:17] [12.34.56.789] [username] [R] D/Data/Shared/Files/ABC Real Estate - Not the bridge Project/Formal Discovery/2016-04-27 Docs from OC (to be processed)/12-15-13 IW CCTV Inspect/My Pane/3738/2013.08.14_0941/Reports/
```

Here is my current script that I have tried so many things on:

```
#!/bin/bash

code23() {

egrep 'code\ 23' -C5 $1 | egrep '\[[A-Z]\/.*' | awk -F\] '{print $6}' | tee ${1}_code_error_files.txt

awk -F\/ '{print $1 "/" $2 "/" $3 "/"}' ${1}_code_error_files.txt | sed 's/\[//g' | sed 's/^\s*\[//g' | sort -u | tee ${1}_code23_errors_dirs.txt

}


if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
   echo "Usage: $ bash get_errors logfile.txt"
   echo "Please use a file containing the IDrive or IBackup command logs."
else   
   code23
fi
```

The series of commands I ran were in the above-referenced function `code23()`

What I do is download the logs from my UI as rtf files. I `cat` those files into one file. Bash has no problem reading these as text files. I ran the following series of commands on these files and it have me the desired output, which is to get the parent directories of the lines that have a code 23 error:

```
`egrep 'code\ 23' -C5 error_file.txt egrep '\[[A-Z]\/.*' | awk -F\] '{print $6}' | sort -u > output_file.txt`
# This successfully printed the full file path of the file that caused the error.

`awk -F\/ '{print $1 "/" $2 "/" $3 "/" }' output_file.txt | sort -u`
 # This successfully prints the first three directories of the folders that contain errors.

 'sed 's/\[//g' output_file.txt
 # I edited the output file with vim to clean it up, by removing the spaces in front of each line, and remove the `[` in front of each directory.
```

Please let me know what I am doing incorrectly.

Thanks to all of your help, I edited the code as follows and it works great now:

```
#!/bin/bash

code23() {

egrep 'code\ 23' -C5 $1 | egrep '\[[A-Z]\/.*' | awk -F\[ '{print $7}' | sort -u | tee $1_code23_error_files.txt | awk -F\/ '{print $1 "/" $2 "/" $3 "/"}' | sed 's/^\s*\[//g' | sort -u | tee $1_code23_error_dirs.txt

}

if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
   echo "Usage: $ bash get_errors logfile.txt"
   echo "Please use a file containing the ABC Company or XYZ Company command logs."
else   
   code23 "$1" 
fi
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's with all the backticks? Are those literal?

Comment: Please try to comply with http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please add your expected output from your sample log file.  You don't really want back-tics around your last `egrep` and `awk` lines, do you? Use 4 spaces at the front of a line to have it appear as code/data/errMsg/etc. And, read the `help` section on editing. Good luck.

Comment: I'd clean up the code first-- you have a lot of unneeded pipes.  Awk can handle a lot of what is being done.  You certainly don't need to pipe your sed to another sed.   e.g. try this: `sed 's/\[//g; s/^\s*\[//g'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script doesn't forward its arguments to `code23`. Functions in bash don't inherit the command line arguments (`$1`, `$2`, etc) of the parent script. You must call a bash function, explicitly providing arguments to it (as if it were a separate program):

```
code23 "$1"
```

Comment: Feel free to take a look at my modified script. I was able to connect those two lines in my function without issue and this helped. Also, passing the argument `$1` helped tremendously. Thank you!